# Can't login: Recevied fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

I am trying to enable GitHub into my PhpStorm project but when I am going to `Settings > Version Control` and add my GitHub credentials then, getting this error:

[image]

Somewhere I found that it may be related to Java JDK but I checked it is correctly given in my environment variable.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have an older PhpStorm version and maybe this could be the problem. I once also had this problem and just logged in via a Token.